# Compile Z3python?

Tags: python, z3

I want to have Z3python on my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I downloaded Z3 source, and compiled like below:

```
$autoconf
$./configure
$sudo make
$sudo make a
$sudo make o
```

Everything went well, but then I tried:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import z3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named z3
```

It seems Z3python is not installed yet? I followed exactly the instructions in README, but it seems to miss something regarding Python binding?

Answer (score 1):

please ignore, what i got is the old version of Z3.

a recommendation: please provide the source code of the latest Z3 in the homepage. i couldnt find it anywhere, then wrongly got the old version. finally, i had to download the latest version from the SourceControl, which was a bit tricky.

Comment: We don't provide the zip files with source code because codeplex can generate the zip file for any version/commit/branch of the codebase. See http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2012/11/11/reorg-z3.html

Comment: if so, please provide the link to the zip file at the homepage, so others will not make a mistake getting the old source.,

Comment: if so, at least please provide the link to the zip file at the homepage, so others will not make a mistake getting the old source. finding the link to the zip file in SourceControl interface is a bit tricky, and not intuitive. thanks!

Comment: I tried that some time ago. Unfortunately, for some strange reason, the Download button is not a real link, but some javascript stuff. So, I can't add a link to it in the homepage. I added some instructions instead. I also put a warning in the old zip files saying they are not the latest release.